# Objective-c Workaround for running intepretted code

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm used to using eval() in languages like javascript e.t.c.

In cocos2d, to select the level, I am passing "1" or "2" to my Loadlevel.m file, the level Classes are named "LevelOne" and "LevelTwo" accordingly, I wanted to create a dictionary lookup that paried "1" => "LevelOne" e.t.c then run eval on that string to effectively call [MyLevel node];

Apparently we can't use eval in IOS code, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `NSStringFromClass` and `NSClassFromString` functions.

Specifically, represent the classes as strings in your dictionary, e.g.,

```
[myDictionary setObject:NSStringFromClass([LevelOne class]) forKey:@"1"]
```

Then, to use the right level from your dictionary, you could do:

```
NSString *levelAsString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"1"];
id node = [NSClassFromString(levelAsString) node]
```

(I'm assuming `+node` is a class method)

Now, this is a pretty uncommon and odd design in Cocoa. Perhaps if you explain more about what you're doing, we could suggest alternate design choices that might be better.

Comment: beautifuly expalined thankyou, already implemented and running :) I'm very new to Objective-c haha

Comment: There's no need to convert the classes to and from strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not one hundred percent clear on what you're asking, but you can store class objects directly in your dictionary, retrieve them, and send them messages:

```
NSDictionary * d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[LevelOne class], @"1", [LevelTwo class], @"2", nil];

Class selectedLevel = [d objectForKey:@"1"];

[selectedLevel node];
```